# Issue with heroku deploy - push to heroku does not seem to be working.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Attempting to deploy my app to heroku. Im not really sure of the issue, as can be seen below, I have used the dotenv gem and basic authentication. Can anyone offer me some help. I can not find any comprehensive answers on linve Thanks

```
> remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
>     remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
>     remote:  !
>     remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
>     remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
>     remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
>     remote:  !     rake aborted!
>     remote:  !     LoadError: cannot load such file -- dotenv
>     remote:  !     /tmp/build_42cddfee1412c60445a7a20452697211/config/application.rb:4:in
> `require'
>     remote:  !     /tmp/build_42cddfee1412c60445a7a20452697211/config/application.rb:4:in
> `<top (required)>'
>     remote:  !     /tmp/build_42cddfee1412c60445a7a20452697211/Rakefile:4:in `require'
>     remote:  !     /tmp/build_42cddfee1412c60445a7a20452697211/Rakefile:4:in `<top
> (required)>'
>     remote:  !     /tmp/build_42cddfee1412c60445a7a20452697211/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in
> `load'
>     remote:  !     /tmp/build_42cddfee1412c60445a7a20452697211/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in
> `load_rakefile'
>     remote:  !     /tmp/build_42cddfee1412c60445a7a20452697211/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:686:in
> `raw_load_rakefile'
>     remote:  !     /tmp/build_42cddfee1412c60445a7a20452697211/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in
> `block in load_rakefile'
>     remote:  !     /tmp/build_42cddfee1412c60445a7a20452697211/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in
> `standard_exception_handling'
>     remote:  !     /tmp/build_42cddfee1412c60445a7a20452697211/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in
> `load_rakefile'
>     remote:  !     /tmp/build_42cddfee1412c60445a7a20452697211/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in
> `block in run'
>     remote:  !     /tmp/build_42cddfee1412c60445a7a20452697211/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in
> `standard_exception_handling'
>     remote:  !     /tmp/build_42cddfee1412c60445a7a20452697211/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in
> `run'
>     remote:  !     /tmp/build_42cddfee1412c60445a7a20452697211/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in
> `<top (required)>'
>     remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `load'
>     remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `<main>'
>     remote:  !
>     remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:102:in
> `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks
> (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
>     remote: ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
>     remote: and using the production group of your Gemfile.
>     remote: rake aborted!
>     remote: LoadError: cannot load such file -- dotenv
```

My gem file is

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'



gem 'rails', '4.2.5'

gem 'pg'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'

gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"

gem 'dotenv-heroku'


group :development, :test do

  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do

  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  gem 'spring'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gem `dotenv-heroku` should be inside the `:development` group.
The purpose of the gem is to pull/push the current heroku config into/from a .env file locally.